# SQL Server Reporting Server slow on first connection

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have a newly installed Reporting Server that is in an availability group. The first time any report is executed, it seems to take about 30-40 seconds to return the results.

I know this is some sort of connection issue because subsequent execution of the reports are quick. If the connection is idle for some time, it seems to try and make the connection again and takes the 30-40 seconds.

Is this normal behavior and is there a workaround?

Comment: Not normal.  Is either the report server database or the report data source accessed through an Availability Group Listener on a Multi-Subnet AG?  When older client libraries connect to a multi-subnet AG Listener without setting the MultiSubnetFailover connection string property they can take a long time (30+ sec) to timeout when trying to connect to the inactive subnet IP address of the listener.

Comment: Thanks David, you put me on the right track I think. The listener resolves to 2 different IP addresses, the first one times out, so it might be a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

> The listener resolves to 2 different IP addresses, the first one times out

Since the the SQL Server native client establish connections to all IP addresses in parallel should not be an issue at DNS side as the client driver will establish connection with first success IP bound and discard any pending connection attempts.

However, in your case you may avoid slowness by setting `MultiSubnetFailover=Yes` in connection string as the client retries TCP connection attempts faster than the operating system's default TCP re-transmit intervals. [Source..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/sql-server-native-client-support-for-high-availability-disaster-recovery?view=sql-server-2017#connecting-with-multisubnetfailover)

Comment: That's awesome.. Where do I set that parameter?

Comment: Hi @user2496011, you can add it part of the report's/data-set's data-source connection string that you have been configured in SSRS report builder/SSDT for VS

Comment: I've added this and still doesn't make any difference.